# Is it useless to do unit tests after writing code?

Tags: unit-testing

I finished an app and after that I'm trying to write unit test to cover all methods.

The thing is that I'm seeing that I'm testing my code with the knowledge of how it works.

For me it is a bit stupid because I know how the code works and I'm testing what my code is actually doing.

Is this useless? I'm testing what it does, not what it's supposed to do. My code works but I can improve it. Then:

Should I complete all my tests and then try to refactor my code changing my test to "How the code should work" and making the changes to the app to pass the test?

Comment: you should always keep the bar green :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to test "How the code should work". That is, you have a clear idea of what a particular method should behave like, then create the set of tests that covers that behaviour. If your code fails the test then you can fix it.

Even though your code is working now you still need the tests for regression testing. Later when you modify your code or add new extensions to it you need to ensure that you did not break the existing functionality. The set of tests that you derive today will be able to tell you how well you did.

Comment: That is good. But even when I try to decouple my code, maybe changing one method will break some others that are not tested yet, that's why I said to write test first and then refactor (to see the red lights on other methods when I change something)

Comment: @Jesus Rodriguez Yes. That is right. Code with adequate test coverage is easier to modify. So for that reason it is always better to complete the tests.

Comment: Having to modify tests after a refactoring (if there is interface change) may be a pain, but the pain will guide you to do better design in the future. ("No pain, no gain") It is also a good way to illustrate whether the public interface is robust enough toward future code changes - in effect, it makes you feel the user's pain when an interface is changed.

Answer (score 5):

While I don't always do Test-Driven Development (write tests before implementing the class), I do always write tests after I implement the code. Even some days after. At least I try to follow a path coverage strategy (that is, every route flow from the beginning to the method up to when it returns). Also for unexpected parameter values. This is useful for enhancing your confidence of correct behaviour of your functions, also when you change the code.

Quite always I find unexpected behaviors or little bugs :) So it works

Answer (score 3):

It will be extremely useful if you ever change the code.

Comment: And for a number of reasons. Such as having clear examples of what code should behave like.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty useless, I'd say. It is called "test driven" for a reason. Every line of code is motivated by a test.

That means the code line is also protected against changes.

Test driven development requires a minimalistic approach and tons of discipline. Add a test to extend the functionality a little. Implement the functionality so it just makes the light green but nothing more. Make foolish implementations until the tests force you to make serious ones.

I have tried to add tests to existing code and found it difficult. The tendency is that only some of the functionality becomes tested. This is dangerous since the test suite will make people think the code is protected. One method is to go through the code line by line and ensure there is a test for it. Make foolish changes to the code until a test forces you to back to the original version. In the end, any change to the code should break the tests.

However, there is no way you can derive the requirements from the code. No test suite that is the result of reverse-engineering will be complete.

Answer (score 1):

You should at least *try* to build the tests on how its supposed to work. Therefor it is better to build the tests in advance, but it is still not useless to build the tests now.

The reason: you don't build the tests to test your current code, but you're building them to test future modifications. Unit tests are especially useful to test if a modification didn't break earlier code.

Answer (score 0):

**Better late than never!**

Of course, the best option is to do the unit tests before you start implementing so that you can profit from them even more, but having a good set of unit tests will prevent you from introducing many bugs when you refactor or implement new features, regardless of whether you implemented the unit tests before or after the implementation.

Comment: This can give a false impression that the code is test-driven, when it is not. Here is a good example of code where a few tests have been added afterwards, giving the garbage a shiny look: http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com